# Powershell - Get Item Sequence # ForEach-Object for Error Handling

Tags: powershell

I want to pass sequence counts for Try/Catch error handling purposes. If my code catches an error, I'd like to be able to return something like "File 2 of 4 failed" without incriminating a sequence variable. I have the following so far:

```
($hash = @(Get-ChildItem C:\Dir -Recurse -Include *.txt) | Where {$_.length -gt 0}) | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.BaseName
    Write-Host $hash.IndexOf($_)
}
"Array Count = $($hash.Count)"
```

This will output:

```
File1
0
File2
1
Array Count = 2
```

I'm not sure how to get the Index number outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Use a global variable.

Add inside the `ForEach-Object` a statement such as:

```
$x = $hash.IndexOf($_);
```

When the loop stops, the variable `$x` will contain the index number.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. I went with $hash.IndexOf($_)+1 to get a sequential count.

Answer (score 0):

Really just more of the same (and a test of PowerShell formatting support).

```
($Hash = Get-ChildItem C:\Dir -Force -Include *.txt -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Length -gt 0 }) |
    ForEach-Object -Begin { "There are $($Hash.Count) non-zero length items.`r`n" } -Process { '{0:000} {1}' -f ($Hash.IndexOf($_) + 1), $_.Name }
```

Which might output:

```
There are 3 non-zero length items.

001 This.txt
002 That.txt
003 And The Other Thing.txt
```